# How to filter a ICollectionView from text box with a delay

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a collectionview that I want to filter from the text of a textbox, but I want to wait 1 second after each character typed to filter to prevent filtering at each character and having poor performance ( the collection is really big).

I have something like this:

```
private System.Timers.Timer filterTimer;
private ICollectionView collectionView;

private void FilterTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    filterTimer.Stop();
    filterTimer = new Timer(1000);
    filterTimer.AutoReset = false;
    filterTimer.Elapsed += delegate {ProcessFilterTextChanged(sender);};
    filterTimer.Start();
}

private void ProcessFilterTextChanged(object source)
{
    collectionView.Refresh();
}

private bool CollectionFilter(object item)
{
    var filterStrings = tbFilter.Text.ToLower();
    //filtering happens here
}
```

Whenever I do this the tbfilter.text throws and exception saying it is owned by another thread.  How would something like this be done safely?

Comment: You are using `System.Timers.Timer`, correct?

Comment: This is a compiler error:  `var filterStrings = filterStrings` ... cannot use `filterStrings` before it is declared.

Comment: Can you show where you are calling CollectionFilter?

Comment: sorry for the compiler error and yes it is System.timers.timer I added the declaration just to be sure.

Comment: collectionView.Filter = CollectionFilter;

Comment: One more questions, what is the type of `collectionView`? Control?

Comment: ICollectionView, added to the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

Get a synchronization handle: `SynchronizationContext.Current`

```
private SynchronizationContext _sync;

_sync.Post((state) => {
   // filter timer code here
}, null);
```

Caveat: This is untested.

`Post` queues the encapsulated functions on the thread pool and will be executed, presumably by the correct thread.

With some tests, it may be possible to get a handle of the thread that `filterTimer` is executing on. I'll check this out and see what I find.

**Update**
After some modification, see if this works:

```
  private SynchronizationContext _sync;

  public Form1() {
     InitializeComponent();
     _sync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
  }

  private void FilterTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if (filterTimer != null) {
        filterTimer.Stop();
        filterTimer.Elapsed -= delegate { ProcessFilterTextChanged(sender); };
     }

     filterTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000) {
        AutoReset = false
     };

     filterTimer.Elapsed += delegate { ProcessFilterTextChanged(sender); };
     filterTimer.Start();
  }

  private void ProcessFilterTextChanged(object source) {
     _sync.Post((state) => {
        collectionView.Filter = CollectionFilter;
        collectionView.Refresh();
     }, null);
  }

  private bool CollectionFilter(object item) {
     var filterStrings = tbFilter.Text.ToLower();
     //filtering happens here
  }
```

The `Timer` fires on a thread other than the UI thread. By using the `_sync.Post` method, we can enqueue the execution of the elapsed delegate so that it runs on the UI thread. Basically, this marshals the execution to the proper thread.

Comment: I was able to construct a test that works with this solution.